# Freezing problems after adding Dragonborn on XBox360

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I got the Dawnguard and Dragonborn add-ons for my Xbox a few weeks ago. While my Dawnguard worked fine, my Dragonborn only added a few new bits to my game; I couldn't find the cultist or the ship in Windhelm at all.

I re-downloaded Dragonborn and now I can do the Dragonborn quests, but the game keeps freezing on me. And there is a delay in the speech and sound of the game, or the sound doesn't come on at all.

I have tried deleting my saved games and starting again and I still have the same problem.  I have checked to make sure my XBox is not overheating.  All my other games are fine; it's only Skyrim that has this problem and only since re-downloading Dragonborn. I have also checked to see if the file was corrupt and it doesn't appear to be.

I found other similar problems, but they are all with the game installed on the hard drive, and I only have the add-ons on my hard drive. How can I fix these problems with the Dragonborn add-on?

Answer (score 2):

Wipe everything Skyrim-related from your hard drive(local installations of Skyrim, save games, DLC, etc). Install Skyrim to your Hard Drive, and re-download all DLC, then start a new game. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my skyrim after I downloaded dragonborn but I figure it out. The way to get it to stop freezing is to disconnect the Internet from the system. I took out my cord and disconnected it from the WiFi and it has been working perfect since.